# MacOS-style Opening files via console with their default applications

Tags: console, macosx

Is there are way to use the MacOS command `open` to open files with their default applications like e.g. `open mytext.pdf` or `open myprogramm.java`. Can Ubuntu be extended in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `xdg-open <your-file>`.

```
   xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a
   URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web
   browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the preferred
   application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file, ftp, http
   and https URLs.
```